# Streaming a file in parts - not working

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I have a client server application that communicate through wcf at transfare mode stream.
when the client try to download the file in one peace, its working but when The client try to take the whole file in 2 peaces, the file that downloaded is damaged and can not be open.

Client Code:

```
public void DownloadPart(Part Part) //Part: Part.From,Part.To -> possitions in the stream from where to begin and when to end reading
                {
                    int ReadUntilNow = 0;
                    int ReadNow = 0;
                    byte[] Array= new byte[15000];
                    long NeedToDownload = Part.To - Part.From;
                    using (FileStream MyFile = new FileStream(Path_To_Save_The_File, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        MyFile.Position = Part.From;
                        while (ReadUntilNow < NeedToDownload)
                        {
                            ReadNow = this.SeederInterface.GetBytes(TorrentID, Part.From + ReadUntilNow, ref Array);
                            ReadUntilNow += ReadNow;
                            MyFile.Write(Array, 0, ReadNow);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Server Code:

```
public int GetBytes(int TorrentID, int Position, ref byte[] Array)
        {
            FileStream File = new FileStream(FilePatch, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            File.Position = Position;
            return File.Read(Array, 0, Array.Length);
        }
```

**Im really hopeless and dont know what is the problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to overwrite any existing output file. You have:

```
using (FileStream MyFile = new FileStream(Path_To_Save_The_File, 
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

That will create a new file, or overwrite the existing file.

In the next line, you have:

```
MyFile.Position = Part.From
```

That will extend the file, and the first part of the file will contain garbage--whatever was on the disk in that space.

I think what you want is to change the `Mode` in your open call to `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, as in:

```
using (FileStream MyFile = new FileStream(Path_To_Save_The_File, 
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

That will open the file if it already exists. Otherwise it will create a new file.

You'll probably want to determine if you're downloading the first part of the file (i.e. a new file), and delete any existing file if so. Otherwise, your code could overwrite the first part of the new file, but not truncate.

Comment: wow thats was my mistake... i cant belive it. Thank you so much for your time! I still cant belive I didnt saw it! Thank you agian!